# Applet program not running in Netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, applet, jgrasp

I am supposed to write an applet that displays a thermometer that can be adjusted with a slider. I believe I have the GUI and everything figured out. In JGrasp (what I normally use) it asks me if I want to run it as an applet and then everything works fine. For my current class my instructor wants everything to be done in NetBeans and I get no error but when I run the applet nothing happens. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

```
package thermometer;

/**
* MTCH_HRTG
*/
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Thermometer extends JApplet implements ChangeListener {

// Container
private Container contentPane;
// Panels
private JPanel sliderP;
private JPanel displayP;
private JPanel titleP;
//Slider
private JSlider slider;
//Labels
private JLabel title;
private JLabel tempL;
//Textfield
private JTextField temp;

public void init () {
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout (new BorderLayout ());

    // Setting the panels and objects
    titleP = new JPanel ();
    displayP = new JPanel ();
    sliderP = new JPanel ();

    title = new JLabel ("Adjust the slider to change the temperature");
    titleP.add(title);

    // Creates the thermometer
    slider = new JSlider (JSlider.VERTICAL, -50, 120, 70);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);

    slider.addChangeListener(this);
    sliderP.add(slider);

    temp = new JTextField ("70", 2);
        temp.setEditable(false);
        tempL = new JLabel ("Degrees in Fahrenheit");

    displayP.add(temp);
    displayP.add(tempL);

    //Adding the panels to the content pane
    contentPane.add(titleP, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(sliderP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(displayP, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
    public void stateChanged (ChangeEvent e)    {
        int temperature = slider.getValue();
            temp.setText(Integer.toString(temperature));
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

}

}
```

Comment: NetBeans seems to be picking up on `public static void main(String[] args) {` & attempting to run the applet as an application. Since the `main` method is empty, it achieves nothing (that's useful). Remove it. More generally, the instructor needs a slap upside the head for getting students to work with applets at all. They are a dead technology, are no longer supported in browsers, teach nothing useful and should not be mentioned in class situations, let alone studied.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! And yeah that's how I felt when I saw we were doing applets...